# Custom iterator and itertools.tee problem

Tags: python, iterator, python-itertools

My custom iterator should call a specific method when next is called on it. It works that way initially, but after itertools.tee is called on the iterator for the second time the method is not called.

I actually already have a solution/workaround but I'd like to understand the root cause of the problem.

```py
class MyIterator(object):
    def __init__(self, elements):
        self._elements = iter(elements)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        element = (self._elements)

        if isinstance(element, HwState):
            element.el_method()

        return element

elements = list(...)
iterator1, iterator2 = itertools.tee(MyIterator(elements))
element1 = next(iterator2)    # ok
element2 = next(iterator2)    # ok
iterator1, iterator2 = itertools.tee(MyIterator(iterator1))
element1 = next(iterator2)    # el_method() is not called but correct element is returned
element2 = next(iterator2)    # el_method() is not called but correct element is returned
```

I "solved" the issue this way:

```py
elements = list(...)
iterator = MyIterator(elements)
element1 = next(iterator)
element2 = next(iterator)
iterator = MyIterator(elements)
element1 = next(iterator)    # el_method() is called, correct element is returned
element2 = next(iterator)    # el_method() is called, correct element is returned
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the "roughly equivalent" implementation of [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) included in the documentation:

```
def tee(iterable, n=2):
    it = iter(iterable)
    deques = [collections.deque() for i in range(n)]
    def gen(mydeque):
        while True:
            if not mydeque:             # when the local deque is empty
                try:
                    newval = next(it)   # fetch a new value and
                except StopIteration:
                    return
                for d in deques:        # load it to all the deques
                    d.append(newval)
            yield mydeque.popleft()
    return tuple(gen(d) for d in deques)
```

Essentially, `tee` keeps a queue for every generated iterator. When a new value is requested, if there is something in the iterator queue it takes the next value from there, and if the queue is empty it calls `next` on the original iterator once and adds the result to every queue. What this means is that the generated values are "cached" and returned by each iterator, instead of duplicating the work of producing the element.

Moreover, it would be in general impossible for `tee` to behave as you expect, since `tee` cannot know how to make copies of an iterator in general. Think for example on a text file. Once you read one line in principle you cannot go back (in simple sequential access), and there is no such thing as "duplicating the file iterator" as such (to emulate something like that you would need multiple file handlers or seeking), so you just save the lines you read and return them later in the other iterators.

Comment: I still needed to run the code in debugger to understand it, but now I know why it works like that. Thanks!

Though I don't understand why tee doesn't know how to copy an iterator. I'm more familiar with C++ and in that case it'd be quite easy as the address of ```next``` would be copied to the new object

Comment: @ArturStępniak The problem is that in Python an iterator can be many different things. For example, a network stream can be read as an iterator, but it cannot be copied (you can buffer what you have read, like `tee` does, but you can not "re-read" the data). Likewise, generator functions produce iterators for which there is no method of copying (the iterator essentially holds a call stack). Collection iterators could be copied in principle I suppose but the only method that "always works" is caching. Hope that helps some.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you